# Edit ansible vault file in Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ansible, ansible-vault

I have issue with editing ansible vault file in Visual studio code.

Example from nest question is not working - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101071/how-can-i-edit-ansible-vault-encrypted-files-in-visual-studio-code

I exported editor like `export EDITOR='code --wait'` and command `ansible-vault edit file1.yml` is still opening an **empty** tmp file in Visual Studio Code.

I use Windows 10 WSL in terminal from VS code. Can someone please advice on this issue or help me to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same procedure is working for me. It did do the following:

```
Updating VS Code Server to version 3db7e09f3b61f915d03bbfa58e258d6eee843f35
Removing previous installation...
Downloading: 100%
Unpacking: 100%
```

I think this comes from the [Remote Development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) set of extensions.